# Sorting an ArrayList by the second word in a string

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've currently got a .txt file i need to read and output data based on what is inside. I've currently got the file to open and saved each line in the file into an ArrayList.

The .txt file is setup like this ;

- 2380213012999 1508434343432 david dead
- 4327482397488 7439857934858 john alive
- 3857948998099 2222783749887 martin killed kelly
- 3857948998099 2222783749887 john killed david

Current code ;

```
 {
    try {
        File file = new File("input.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> txtline = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            txtline.add(line);
            System.out.println(txtline);
        }

        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I'm just wondering if there is a way to sort each line of text by the 2nd large number, I've looked and I just can't seem to find anything. A point in the right direction or some guidance would be amazing as I'm currently stumped as I need to do this before i progress any further.

Comment: One generally defines a `Comparator` implementation to provide for sorting objects into other than their natural order (including if they have no natural order).  You can use an instance of such a `Comparator` together with `Collections.sort()` to sort your `List`.

Comment: But for efficiency, I would suggest parsing out the sort keys in advance, and storing them alongside their corresponding strings in objects of a class you define for the purpose.  Then sort *those*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the task at hand by creating a stream of the list, passing in a `Comparator` object to the `sorted` method to define the *sort key* and then collect it into an `ArrayList`.

comparing numerically:

```
txtline = txtline.stream()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong((String e) -> Long.parseLong(e.split(" ")[1])))                             
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

comparing by strings:

```
txtline = txtline.stream()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String e) -> e.split(" ")[1]))
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: This works great thanks! - so this splits each of the objects in the arraylist and splits each by whitespace into an array, and then sorts the 2nd object in the array ? am i correct in thinking that, it's just i want to fully understand it ! thanks btw !

Comment: @JorD yup so we basically _extract_ the second number of each line by splitting it with the `" "` delimiter and taking the 2nd element and that's then sorted by the extracted key. Also, you can say thanks by accepting the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put this after your while-loop

```
java.util.Collections.sort(txtLine, new Comparator<String>() {
    public void compare(String lineA, String lineB) {
        String wordA2 = lineA.split(" ")[1];
        String wordB2 = lineB.split(" ")[1];
        return wordA2.compareTo(wordB2);
    }
});
```

Can be done more efficiently, but the code doesn't get much shorter than this (unless you use lambdas).

```
java.util.Collections.sort(txtLine, (String lineA, String lineB) -> {
        String wordA2 = lineA.split(" ")[1];
        String wordB2 = lineB.split(" ")[1];
        return wordA2.compareTo(wordB2);
});
```

Comment: `txtLine.sort(Comparator.comparing(line -> line.split(" ")[1]));`

Comment: Btw this won't work if it's supposed to be sorted numerically.

Comment: @shmosel You're right... but looking at the format of the data in the question, that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, i looked at comparators but couldn't get my head fully around it so wanted a little more explanation, also i do want them sorted numerically by the 2nd number within the string, is that possible? Thanks for replying so quickly btw !

Comment: @JorD If they're equal-length, you can sort them as strings.